# How should I pass info through email headers in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sendgrid, email-headers, cloudmailin

I'm working on a support app which would allow customers to mail to support@myapp.com and reply to this same email address. I have set up ticket+[id]@myapp.com to be visible within the support team whenever there's a new ticket created. I am using Cloudmailin for the incoming emails and SendGrid for outgoing.

I want to be able to store the ticket ID in the email headers of the email that is sent to the customer from support@myapp.com. When the customer replies to support@myapp.com, the app will then read the headers and know which ticket ID to route to. I have read up that it is not recommended to include X-custom headers as it would get stripped off by some mail servers.

There are some suggestions to use the Reply-To header to store the ticket ID but I can't seem to find that header in Cloudmailin.

Appreciate any suggestion on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea in using the +'s to differentiate the emails. To read the incoming email header, you can use the headers[to] in cloudmailin.

```
Message Sender <sender@example.com>
------cloudmailinboundry
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers[To]"
```

[Cloudmailin headers file](http://docs.cloudmailin.com/http_post_formats/multipart/#headers)

Comment: So, when sending the email, do I set the headers['Reply-To'] = ticketID?

Comment: Yup. You may need to authorize your entire domain in case it is not with SendGrid, otherwise you may end up in somebodies spam filter - (I'm not too familiar with SendGrid but it is a pretty common problem that most outgoing email providers have solved).

Comment: Thanks for that tip of authorizing the domain. Still a little confused about Reply-To headers, when the customer hit reply , they will be able to see the Reply-To email address which would be something like Ticket+id@myapp.com?

Comment: Yes they will - you can even just leave reply-to null and set the sender as the ticker+id@myapp.com address.

Comment: would including this info in Message-ID be an option?

Comment: Message-ID is supposed to be unique for each individual email sent, and it isn't guaranteed that an email provider wouldn't wipe it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kelz. Will experiment with Reply-To headers then